# FFMpeg v4l2m2m green output

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, v4l2

I'm using hardware encoding via FFMPEG and h264_v4l2m2m codec.

If I'm using FFmpeg h264_v4l2m2m, the encoded video looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZwEv.png)

```
ffmpeg -i small.mp4 -vcodec h264_v4l2m2m grb_2-v4l2.avi

[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x13d24d0] driver 'bcm2835-codec' on card 'bcm2835-codec-isp'
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x13d24d0] driver 'bcm2835-codec' on card 'bcm2835-codec-encode'
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x13d24d0] Using device /dev/video11
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x13d24d0] driver 'bcm2835-codec' on card 'bcm2835-codec-encode'
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x13d24d0] Failed to set number of B-frames
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x13d24d0] Failed to set header mode
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x13d24d0] Failed to set gop size
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x13d24d0] h264 profile not found
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x13d24d0] Encoder adjusted: qmin (0), qmax (51)
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x13d24d0] Failed to set minimum video quantizer scale
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x13d24d0] Failed to set maximum video quantizer scale
```

And while processing:

```
[avi @ 0x145aa20] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 0, current: 0; changing 
to 1. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
```

If the video container is not AVI, then the resulting video is blank.

I want to use this encoder as a backend codec for OpenCV. If I'm trying to use it, I'm getting the following error:

```
This encoder requires using the avcodec_send_frame() API
```

What is the workaround and where should I look?

- Machine: Raspberry Pi 4B+
- System: Custom Yocto Distribution (master branches)
- OpenCV version: 4.1.0
- FFMpeg version: 4.2.2

Comment: Show the full log from the command.

Comment: @llogan https://pastebin.com/c3D6901N

Comment: Do you get a bad output if you use a different encoder, such as `-c:v mpeg4`?

Comment: @llogan No, the output from other codecs is fine.

Comment: I don't have the hardware to try it myself. Consider asking the ffmpeg-user mailing list.

Comment: @RomanHoncharenko any success with it?
I have same problem when using ffmpeg with h264_v4l2m2m encoder.
I also get Non-monotonous DTS message when starting encoding.